# Calculating Levi-Civita Connection and Curvature for Euclidean Metric

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, manifolds, curvature, connections

So we want to...

**i.)** Calculate the Levi-Civita Connection of two vector fields X,Y: $$\nabla_{X}Y$$ for the standard euclidean metric in n-dimensions: $$ds^{2} = dx_{1}^{2} + ... + dx_{n}^{2}$$

**ii.)** Calculate the curvature function of this metric for n = 2.

---

So for...

**i.)** I have for the covariant derivative of two vector fields, $V = v^{i}e_{i}$ and $U = u^{j}e_{j}$ that $\nabla_{V}U$ = $v^{i}u^{j}\Gamma^{k}_{ij}e_{k} + v^{i}\frac{du^{j}}{dx^{i}}e_{j}$

- However looking online I found an example where it looked like all he was doing was calculating the christoffel symbols. I was going to calculate $\Gamma^{i}_{ii}, \Gamma^{i}_{ij} = \Gamma^{i}_{ji}, \Gamma^{i}_{jj}, \Gamma^{j}_{ii}, \Gamma^{j}_{ij} = \Gamma^{j}_{ji}$ and $\Gamma^{j}_{jj}$ and since for the euclidean metric only the diagonal (i.e., i=j) elements are 1 with all else 0 and since the symbols all involve derivatives of metric elements, thus making all the symbols equal to zero right?

> So should I just calculate those Christoffel Symbols for the Levi-Civita Connection (Bothered because doesn't involve Vector Fields at all)? Or should I use that equation for $\nabla_{V}U$ (in which case the term with christoffel symbols vanish leaving only second term and then I don't know how to make a meaningful answer out of components of arbitrary vector fields)?

**ii.)** For this I just need to know what the curvature function is. I know theres a normal curvature which looks to be defined as: $$ K_{N} = <c''(0), N(p)>$$ for a curve c with c(0) = p but I've seen it as $$K_{N} = II(c'(0), c'(0)) where II is 2nd fundamental form.

- I'm not exactly sure how to calculate something with the Second fundamental form if anyone can elucidate this I would appreciate that.

  > Basically I just need to know what formula I should be using to calculate the curvature in n = 2.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since all the $g_{ij}$ are constant, all the Christoffel symbols will be $0$. Your formula for normal curvature is not what is going on here (for starters, we have an abstract Riemannian metric, not a surface in $\Bbb R^3$; next, we want Gaussian curvature, not normal curvature, even in the setting of a surface in $\Bbb R^3$). Do you have a formula for the curvature tensor in terms of things like $\nabla_X\nabla_Y Z$ ... or, perhaps, in terms of the Christoffel symbols and their derivatives?

Comment: So your saying for the Levi-Civita calculation I can basically just calculate the various 'types' of Christoffel Symbols? And so I looked up the Curvature Tensor and it appears that $$R(X,Y)Z = \nabla_{X}\nabla_{Y}Z - \nabla_{Y}\nabla_{X}Z - \nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$$ So given what I've done in the first part would I take Z to be the metric g? And then calculate the chistoffel symbols? What concerns me then would be that for the 3 terms the various vector spaces X, Y and Z and their placement doesn't seem to make a difference in the calculation of $\nabla$ given that in part 1 all that was needed were

Comment: the elements of the metric, $g_{ij}$ and not the elements of the vector spaces.

Comment: What does your course expect you to do for the curvature? I know 50 ways of approaching this, and I can't mind-read. But I guarantee nothing to do with second fundamental form. This is for an abstract Riemannian surface.

Comment: Well we are asked to "calculate the Curvature Function of this metric for n = 2" and then later on in reference to the "Curvature function" the symbol $K_g$ is used, seemingly indicating Gaussian Curvature?

Comment: Also "nothing to do with second fundamental form" is the nicest concatenation of words I've heard all day :)

Comment: As I said, there is a formula for $K$ just in terms of Christoffel symbols and their derivatives. Or you can use that formula and see you get 0 for any vector field $Z$ (choosing $X=\partial/\partial x^1$ and $Y=\partial/\partial x^2$) because all the Christoffel symbols are 0.

Comment: I just noticed on wikipedia there's an alternative definition for the Gauss Curvature that goes like: $$ K = \frac{<(\nabla_{e_{2}}\nabla_{e_{1}} - \nabla_{e_{1}}\nabla_{e_{2}})e_{1}, e_{2}>}{Det(g)}$$ and I think I saw somewhere where it's like the covariant derivative of one basis vector in the direction of another other basis vector equals the christoffel symbols times that basis vector or something along those lines. Would that be your equation?

Comment: Yeah, with $e_1=\partial/\partial x^1$ and $e_2=\partial/\partial x^2$.

Comment: Ah yes and of course we can also say $X = e_{1}$ and $Y = e_{2}$ right? Also I've confirmed the curvature we are talking about is indeed the Gauss Curvature.